# Awk script to get the version info from a Gradle command?

Tags: shell, awk, groovy

I have a Gradle task that prints out the artifact version, like this

```
$ ./gradlew :myproject:printVersion
:myproject:printVersion
2.0

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.976 secs
```

What's an `awk` or shell task to get the `2.0` part that I can use in a Jenkins pipeline? Note currently the artifact version is `2.0`, but can change later to, say, `2.1`, or `3.0` etc.

```
$ ./gradlew :myproject:printVersion | some_awk_code
```

Comment: if it's always the 2nd line: `./gradlew :myproject:printVersion | sed -n '2p'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to replace `some_awk_code` with `awk 'NR==2'` or `sed '2!d'` to get only second row.

Comment: Thanks! This also worked for me `./gradlew :myproject:printVersion | grep '^[0-9]'`